# Linear Equation rearrange

Tags: java, math

I have a formula shows below,

```
((((c1+c2)/c3)*c4)-c5+c6)
```

This formula format can be vary which means this formula generating from the end user. It can be any format. we are using only basic arithmetic operatiors ie, `+`, `-` , `*` , `/` and `(`,`)`.

I can choose any one value to find out. If i choose `C3` to find out the value, the formula needs to be modified like below,

```
C3 = (c1+c2)*(c4/(c5-c6))
```

Suggestion and ideas welcome please. Any API available?

Comment: Think in a queue of actions, then iterate and find the relatio to the data you want.

Comment: **BODMAS** using a stack? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Comment: This kind of sounds like a homework question. If it is, you should probably tag it as such.

Comment: one problem is that some of your chosen values might not have a solution in your arithmetic you selected. For example if you have `((c1*c2*c3*c3*c3) + c4)` and select `c3` you will not get a solution for `c3` with only the `+-*/()` operators.

Comment: Your first line is not a formula but an expression. It's hard to tell the transformation rule from this expression to the desired result. Please double check both lines!

Comment: @Cornelius I believe he's only addressing linear expressions, which would exclude powers.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would consider starting with 2 Collections, one to indicate the left hand side of the equation and one for the right hand side. The RHS would start with just one element, the entire formula. Then, start stripping off parentheses from the outside working in. And as each element becomes exposed, add it to the 2nd collection, making sure to inverse the operation. Then, as soon as you move the element you're searching for, start moving from the 2nd collection back to the first.

Since I really think this is homework, I don't want to give a code answer, but my above gibberish translates to "step through the arithmetic transformations". So, to expose C3:

```
((((c1+c2)/c3)*c4)-c5+c6)
(((c1+c2)/c3)*c4)-c5+c6
(c5 - c6) = (((c1+c2)/c3)*c4)
(c5 - c6) = ((c1+c2)/c3)*c4
((c5 - c6) / c4) = ((c1+c2)/c3)
((c5 - c6) / c4) = (c1+c2)/c3
(c3* ((c5- c6) / c4) = (c1 + c2)
c3* (c5- c6) = (c1 + c2) * c4
c3 = (((c1 + c2) * c4) / (c5 - c6))
```

I'm not entirely certain where I went wrong that my final equation differs from yours, but I believe that is the approach I would take - step through each transformation until the variable you need is exposed.

Comment: Your answer is the same as op's, the grouping is just different. Yours is (a*b)/c, while op's is a*(b/c). I agree with general approach, though i would tend to go the "Object Oriented" approach modeling each operator (+-/*) as an operation with appropriate properties / methods to manipulate itself as part of a larger operation (e.g. formula)

Answer (score 1):

If the target variable occurs an arbitrary number of times, it's impossible (in general) to derive a formula. If it appears only once, the algorithm is quite straightforward. First transform the formula into reverse polish notation. Then build a binary tree, which has variables in the leaves and operations in internal nodes. (It's really simple when you have a reverse polish notation, almost like a calculation of the expression, but with subtrees on the stack instead of numbers.) Process the path from the root to the needed leaf, solving the simplest equations:

```
? + c6 = 0
? = 0 - c6
? - c5 = 0 - c6
? = (0 - c6) + c5
? * c4 = (0 - c6) + c5
? = ((0 - c6) + c5) / c4
(c1+c2)/? = ((0 - c6) + c5) / c4
? = (c1+c2) / (((0 - c6) + c5) / c4)
c3 = (c1+c2) / (((0 - c6) + c5) / c4)
```

Here I denoted by ? the subtree containing the target variable. Note that each equation you need to solve is of form (...) op ? = (...) and hence is solved in an obvious way.